# How to delete memory for std::unique_ptr stored in a vector

Tags: c++11, windows-phone-8, directx, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have a Windows Phone 8 C# project with a C++ DirectX componenet. In the C++ DirectX project, I have a variable defined in my header file:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ParticleRenderer>> m_particleRenderer;
```

In my C++ file, I add new elements to the vector like this:

```
m_particleRenderer.push_back( std::unique_ptr<ParticleRenderer>(new ParticleRenderer(m_d3dDevice, m_d3dContext, m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView)) );
```

I want to delete this memory, how do I go about deleting it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects that are owned by the `shared_ptr`s will be deleted (and thus their memory will be freed) when the `shared_ptr`s are destructed, if there are no other `shared_ptr`s referring to those objects. In this case each of the `shared_ptr`s in `m_particleRenderer` will be destructed when either:

- The object that contains `m_particleRenderer` is destructed (assuming that it is a member of an object).
- The `shared_ptr` is removed from `m_particleRenderer`.

So, if the object that owns `m_particleRenderer` still exists but it no longer has any use for the elements in `m_particleRenderer`, then a simple `m_particleRenderer.clear();` will remove all the `shared_ptr`s from the `vector`. Each removed `shared_ptr` will be destructed. If it is the only `shared_ptr` owning its `ParticleRenderer` then the `ParticleRenderer` will also be destructed. Otherwise the `ParticleRenderer` will continue to exist until the last `shared_ptr` that owns it is destroyed.

Comment: I want to delete any memory used, as I seem to have some memory leaks. That would be the first option, right?  For the 2nd option, what is the difference between "delete the memory" and "destroying them"?

Comment: @Lisa I just noticed that `m_particleRenderer` is storing `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr`, but the first option is most likely what you want. I will update the answer.